# Thickbox inline problem

Tags: thickbox

I am trying to create a modal window with hidden content using thickbox 
It opens the window fine , not sure whys its not showing the content inside the id="hiddencontent".

i am following as suggested in the examples for inline http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/#
-thanks

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="thickbox.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="thickbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>

<body>
<a href="#TB_inline?height=155&width=300&inlineId=hiddenContent" class="thickbox">Show Content</a> 

<div id="hiddenContent" style="display: none">inline content comes here</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems you don't have css file, you can copy thickbox css on http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/#sectiona-3 to your page (or save as style.css file).

-- edit --
Yeh, sorry, didn't notice that css is already loaded :(

By the way, just found the solution, try to add p tag inside your hiddenContent div:

```
<div id="hiddenContent" style="display: none"><p>inline content comes here</p></div>
```

Hope helps ;)

Comment: i checked the path of the css files it seems to be there, not sure why its not pulling the content in the thickbox/modal window. I just get an empty thickbox.

Comment: I Just found something funky if you have the content  inside a <p>tag that makes it work

Comment: Have you try adding p tag inside your div? it works here.. I saw it on thickbox sample code ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in thickbox. Here is how you can fix it:

Inside thickbox.js

on or about line 221 you should see this line of code:

```
$("#TB_ajaxContent").append($('#'+params['inlineId']).children());
```

change it to this:

```
$("#TB_ajaxContent").html($('#'+params['inlineId']).html())
```

and then, on or about line 223 you will see this line:

```
$('#'+params['inlineId']).append($("#TB_ajaxContent").children());
```

disable the line by adding two slashes before it like this:

```
//$('#'+params['inlineId']).append($("#TB_ajaxContent").children());
```

Explanation:

When thickbox copies the content from the hidden div into the thickbox container, it does so by copying all .children() elements. If you have only text inside your hidden div there ARE NO CHILDREN because text is not itself a child element. This is why wrapping your content in a `<p>` tag will work because now there is a child (the `<p>` tag).

So if you want to have text only in your hidden div using `.html()` instead will grab everything in your hidden div. The second line being disabled prevents thickbox from trying to copy the content back to the hidden div when the thickbox closes, which would cause any content within child tags to be duplicated in the hidden div.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to edit the `.js` file, the solution is quite simple.

Maybe a bit later :) but I overcomed the issue only changing the `?` char in `#TB_inline?` by `&`

The issue is on the internal `parseQuery` tickbox function, that parses match pairs but it blows when the query have a double `?` like in the case.

**UPDATE**: In some cases the `<p>` fix is also needed ;)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The function tb_position() needs to be updated.

this condition

**if ( !(jQuery.browser.msie && jQuery.browser.version < 7))**

is the reason for error.

jQuery does not support jQuery.browser anymore. For detecting IE6 in this case change the above condition to this

**if ( !(/\bMSIE 6/.test(navigator.userAgent)))**